Image button without bg/border?
I've been trying to make a button from an image, but I'm not sure how to remove the border and background from it. Is there any way I could have the image act as a button?
This is my current button
And this is my code:
<a title="Go to the card store?" href="https://site"><button type="button"><img src="cardspin.gif" width="200" height="200"></button></a>
I've tried making a custom button class in my .css file, but it didn't do anything. This was the code I used, trying to make the class.
.transparent_button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0px;
    }

It's a pretty simple kind that just leads to another page of my site when clicked, if that has anything to do with it...

You could attach an on click listener to the image instead of wrapping it in an anchor tag. Also, you could then create a css rule to make the cursor a pointer on it.

@tomerpacific that's poor advice and an inaccessible one. Why remove an anchor and then sue CSS and JS to mimic the anchor's behavior instead of using the tool that exists for such cases?

"It's a pretty simple kind that just leads to another page of my site when clicked" - this is typically a use-case for an <a> element, not a <button>. It's also invalid to nest interactive elements.

Note that it is invalid to nest interactive elements within each other. A button is not allowed to be placed inside an anchor. YOu either want an anchor (direct to another resource) or a button (trigger to fire a script).

Do not tag in the title not even [solved]. Rather check the most helpful answer as the correct answer.

To me it looks like, based on the implementation of your code, the only functionality of clicking the button is taking you to the card store.
A button is generally used to perform some kind of action, like submitting a search request or adding an item to a shopping list. I cannot see any action required in your code provided, therefore I would say that you really only require the anchor tag:
<a title="Go to the card store?" href="https://site">
  <img src="cardspin.gif" width="200" height="200">
</a>


You need the image as a .png file. You remove the background in Photoshop.

PNG is not the only image format that allows for transparent backgrounds. SVG and GIF do too. In this case, it is an animated GIF. Nothing you can simply convert to a PNG.

@tacoshy Said by someone that hasn't removed the background frame by frame to get a transparent GIF.
